# Using Apache variables to define IP and Port

Tags: apache, variables, include

I have the two different applications that use the same instances on two Apache servers. On each http server I have the same config for each application - the only difference is the IP address. Is there a way to extract out the IP address from the httpd.conf and include it in the conf or define a variable for the IP address?

Any thoughts would be helpful thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a question for serverfault but I try to guess what you're going for.

So you can include `<VirtualHost *:80>` instead of `<VirtualHost 192.168.0.4:80>` which will probably solve your problem. No need to add the IP there.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'll try on there instead!